# Is it possible to change the default behavior of windows 10 virtual desktops in this way?

Tags: windows, virtual-desktop

When using the virtual desktop feature of windows, I often find that I have one window open that I want to be an a single virtual desktop, and 4-5 windows open I want on all desktop (multiple monitors and what not mean I have a lot of windows open).

It's a major pain to select which windows I want on all desktops when in actuality I only want to change one window.

Is it possible to make it so that all windows are available on all desktops until I explicitly change it?

Comment: "It's a major pain to select which windows I want on all desktops when in actuality I only want to change one window." I'm not really sure what you mean by this. Can you say it in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make it so that all windows are available on all desktops until I explicitly change it?

Yes, but only if you want this to apply to *all* windows of that app.

1. Have more than one virtual desktops and the [app you want to show on all desktops] displayed on the current one [(Source)](https://superuser.com/a/1674974/89165)
2. Enter Task View either by the taskbar icon
   [image]
   or the shortcut
   <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> [(Source)](https://superuser.com/a/1674974/89165)
3. Right click on a window associated with the application you want to open on all desktops
4. Select "Show windows from this app on all desktops":
   [image]

Now, when you **restart the app, it'll automatically show on all virtual desktops.** (I'm not sure why, but the option above it does not persist.)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

Start menu > Settings > System > Multitasking > Virtual Desktops

Play around with the settings and see what you prefer.

Comment: Technically, this doesn't answer the question, but it might be a plan B if nothing else works; this answer might be more suitable as a comment. There are only two dropdowns in those settings: "On the taskbar, show windows that are open on" and "Pressing Alt + Tab shows windows that are open on" They both share the same options: "All desktops" and "Only the desktop I'm using."