# How to show a window on all virtual desktops

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

If using Windows 10's built-in virtual desktop: Is it possible to show a window on all desktops and not only on a single one?

Comment: Are you trying to have the Remote Desktop span multiple screens? If so, you can save the RDP connection and then edit the RDP file directly. This might be useful for you: https://superuser.com/a/1490431

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Do this:

- Have more than one virtual desktops and the window displayed
  on the current one
- Enter Task View either by the taskbar icon
  [image]
  or the shortcut
  <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Right-click the window and select
  "Show this window on all desktops".

For more information and screenshots see the article
[How To Pin An App Window To All Virtual Desktops In Windows 10](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-pin-an-app-window-to-all-virtual-desktops-in-windows-10/).

Comment: Yes, this is the way. But is there a keyboard shortcut for this procedure—or is it possible to create one?

Comment: This comment saved a lot of time and frustration!

Answer (score 1):

@harrymc's answer completely answers the question, but you'll have to follow these steps every time you open the app. Sometimes that's desirable, but other times you want the application to *start* on all virtual desktops every time they open. Here's how you do that:

1. Have more than one virtual desktops and the [app you want to show on all desktops] displayed on the current one (Same step in @harrymc's)
2. Enter Task View either by the taskbar icon
   [image]
   or the shortcut
   <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (Same step in @harrymc's)
3. Right click on a window associated with the application you want to open on all desktops
4. Select "Show windows from this app on all desktops":
   [image]

Now, when you **restart the app, it'll automatically show on all virtual desktops.** (I'm not sure why, but the option above it does not persist.)

Note: this applies to *all* windows of that app.