# Does the term "virtual desktop" mean separate things on Windows 10 compared to Azure?

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I'm trying to learn how to programmatically control the Windows 10 Virtual Deskop. I've found [this library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/windows-virtual-desktop/overview) but it's taking some time to find documentation/examples of my usecase*. [Most of what I find relates to Azure or remote desktops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/windowsvirtualdesktop/?source=recommendations), but I need something for my local desktop. Can these "commandlets" programmatically control the Windows 10 Virtual Deskop, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

*: Admittedly, this is an XY Problem: I'm trying to figure out how to *start* an app in "Show this window on all desktops" mode: as though I opened it, <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, right-clicked it, and selected "Show this window on all desktops."

Comment: We have [multiple](https://superuser.com/questions/1732174/windows-10-batch-show-this-window-on-all-desktops) [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/1371818/how-to-make-windows-remember-the-show-this-window-on-all-desktops-option-even) that use AutoHotKey for this purpose

Comment: @Esther thank you! I'd been looking for https://superuser.com/a/1759214/89165 but couldn't find it after googling for a while. It'd been so long, I couldn't remember that I solved this use case with AHK in the past.

Comment: looks like they are setting exstyle to 0x00000080, which is supposed to be used for a floating toolbar but will also force the window to appear on all desktops, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles

Comment: @Esther I remember a little more detail now: this was one of the questions I found *along the way*, it wasn't the solution I used. One hour later, I finally remember how to do this: https://superuser.com/a/1808313/89165 It's way simpler than I expected. You don't have to install anything, not even official libraries.